# How to merge cell using POI in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, jxl

I want to merge cells using POI in java. I have a input sheet which has merged cells.

First I have to get all the merged cells form that sheet. Then I have to create a new with similarly merged cells.

I got merged cells by method `getNumMergedRegions()`.

Which gave me these values:
`A56:A64=9, A65:A73=9, A2:A8=7, A49:A55=7, A20:A26=7, A9:A19=11, A43:A48=6, A27:A42=16`. Now, I want to create a new sheet and want cell merged based on these values. OR can any one help me with any other way using `JXL api`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CellReference to parse the required String, here is a example:

```
    String[] cellStrings = "A2:A8".split(":");
    CellReference start = new CellReference(cellStrings[0]);
    CellReference end = new CellReference(cellStrings[1]);

    CellRangeAddress address = new CellRangeAddress(start.getRow(),
            end.getRow(), start.getCol(), end.getCol());
    System.out.println(address);
```

This should output:

`org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [A2:A8]`

Then you can use [addMergedRegion](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#addMergedRegion(org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress)) from your HSSFSheet instance.

Comment: Can we do the same using JXL Api

Comment: I don't know JXL Api, never tried. Reading the Docs you have there the jxl.CellReferenceHelper and jxl.Range, suppose the logic is the same

Answer (score 4):

You can use method `sheet.addMergedRegion(rowFrom,rowTo,colFrom,colTo);` find its doc on offical site.

Example:

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,1,4,1));
```

This will merge from B2 to E2

Rough Estimate for you try this A2:A8:

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,9,0,0);
```

Comment: i want something where I can mention A2:A8 and it should merged cells from A2 to A8

Comment: Take a look at CellReference Javadoc, might be useful to parse the String you have to int indexes.

Comment: i want something like this sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(A2:A8));

Comment: For more read doc, If you want in this way, develop your own method to convert AS:A8 into given CellRangeAddress method's args.